# Why does everythink in bootstrap is wrapped in anchor tag?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-grid

i am trying to use bootstrap for the first time in my life and i have a problem with bootstrap grid. When i try to insert - a href="#" tag -into grid it deform it and i really dont know why is that happening. Please help me i am trying to solve this problem for like 2 days.

[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1uis.png) - this is how does it look without

[Deformed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGOAG.png) - this is what happens after puting  tag.

Comment: Found what could be the problem, my div-sm is after adding ahref="" wrapped into <a> but still dont know why is that happening...

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please add a minimum snippet of the source code where the issue can be reproduced, so we can see what you did wrong. From the looks of it, I'd say the issues is malformed html, some tag isn't properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

So  i finally find out a solution for this, it just needed to set all anchor tags to display: contents;. It still didnt give me answer for why is all wrapping into anchor tags but it solve my problem of grid deformation. So for everyone who has the same problem (tbh i dont think there is someone) this is the solution.
in css file or in style on your page -

```
a{
display: contents;
}
```